Message set with "setError()" on a clickable TextView is not shown
I am not able to find the correct configuration for the behaviour I want. I have a layout with 2 TextView for displaying a date (birth and death date). To set both dates, the user touches (onClick() method) the corresponding TextView, so a DatePickerDialog is displayed. Once the user selects a date, this date is set in the TextView. After filling the form, I check all fields, including the dates. Of course, death date can't be earlier than birth date. If that happens, I setError() to both TextView with a message explaining this.
My problem is that the red icon next to the TextView is shown, but not the text. I guess it happens because these two TextView have a style that inherits from @android:style/Widget.EditText and also have android:focusable="false". If I set android:focusable="true", then the message is displayed, but users need to touch twice in the TextView to launch the DatePickerDialog.
Any idea about how to show the message but user having to touch only once to launch the DatePickerDialog?

TextView birthDateTextView = findViewById(R.id.birthDateTextView);
TextView deathDateTextView = findViewById(R.id.deathDateTextView);

// DatePickerDialog setup for birth and death dates
birthDateTextView.setOnClickListener(v -> showDatePickerDialog(birthDateTextView));
deathDateTextView.setOnClickListener(v -> showDatePickerDialog(deathDateTextView));

// Validation check
if (deathDate < birthDate) {
birthDateTextView.setError("Birth date cannot be after death date");
deathDateTextView.setError("Death date cannot be before birth date");
}

This way, you can:
Tap once to show the DatePickerDialog.
Have the error message show correctly if the validation fails.
The key part is to ensure the TextViews remain clickable and interactive, and that setError() functions correctly when the TextViews are in focus.
